# Push Array of items into Array of stores, which is under an Array of StoreType

Tags: javascript, arrays

Developing a JS file that will generate Stores and Items for a board game.

There is an array per store type, for example, there is an array called *BeerStores*. In the BeerStores array is 6 Stores, each store has a *StoreName*, and *StoreWealth*. This is created as follows:

```js
var beerStoreArray = businessCount("Beer Store",5,100,200);

function businessCount(storeType, numStores, min, max) {
            var businessCount = [];
            var x = numStores;
            if (x == 0) {
                return;
            } else {
                while (numStores > 0) {
                    var storeWealth = Math.round(randomIntFromRange(min, max));
                    var storeName = storeType + " " + numStores;
                    businessCount.push({
                        storeName,
                        storeWealth
                    });
                    numStores--;
                }
                return businessCount;
            }
        }
console.log(beerStoreArray);
```

This works great, and outputs the following in console as expected:

```
> 0: {storeName: "Beer Store 5", storeWealth: 140}
> 1: {storeName: "Beer Store 4", storeWealth: 193}
```

etc.

**The issue:**

Now I want to add items inside each Store (e.g. Light Beer) and I am a bit lost. Is there a way I can go through each Store in the *beerStoreArray*, and add *itemName*, and *itemPrice* under it? So that it would output like so:

```
> 0: {storeName: "Beer Store 5", storeWealth: 140 {
    0: {itemName: "Light Beer", price: 10}
    1: {itemName: "Heavy Beer", Price: 12}
    }
> 1: {storeName: "Beer Store 4", storeWealth: 140 {
    0: {itemName: "Light Beer", price: 10}
    1: {itemName: "Heavy Beer", Price: 12}
    }
```

etc.

Thank you for any assistance, I've been really stuck at this part and struggling to find relevant examples.

**Edit**: Fixed the code so that it runs. Please note I don't actually need it to output, it was just my easiest way of explaining how I am trying to structure it. Apologies for the confusion. Essentially, *beerStoreArray* contains several Stores (with values *storeName* and *storeWealth*). I am now trying to add multiple items under each store (with values *itemName* and *itemPrice*). Which I will later list (via document.write).

Comment: It's really helpful with questions that are hard to explain to use valid code. The output you want isn't valid Javascript so it's hard to know what is supposed to be an object and what is an array. (ie. `storeWealth: 140 {...` does the property storeWealth point to a number, object or array?? ) Can you write this in a way that you can execute it without syntax errors? For

Comment: Apologies, when I refer to output I meant when I just do ```console.log(beerStoreArray)```. I don't actually need it to output, it is just easier for me to view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is an object structure like this

```
[
   {
     store_name : "BeerStore",
     store_wealth : 123,
     items : [
        {
          item_name : "Some beer",
          item_price : 20
        }
     ]
   },
   ....
]
```

This could be achieved by doing something like this

```
var stores = [
   {item_name : "Beer Store", store_wealth : 123, items : []},
   {item_name : "Store 1", store_wealth : 0, items : []},
]

var item_one = {item_name : "Some beer", price 20}
var item_one = {item_name : "Some beer #2", price 30}

stores[0].push(item_one);
stores[1].push(item_two);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your expected output is not a valid `json` objects. `json` contains only key-value pair

You cannot just push it to an object. I would suggest you add a new field called `storeItems`.

```
storeItems: {
    0: {itemName: "Light Beer", price: 10}
    1: {itemName: "Heavy Beer", Price: 12}
}
```

To push it into the array, you can do

```
arr[0].storeItems = {
    0: {itemName: "Light Beer", price: 10}
    1: {itemName: "Heavy Beer", Price: 12}
} // likewose for other elements
```

Sample object:

```
0: {storeName: "Beer Store 5", storeWealth: 140, storeItems: {
    0: {itemName: "Light Beer", price: 10}
    1: {itemName: "Heavy Beer", Price: 12}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First iterate over *beerStoreArray* and in each store, keep pushing *itemName* and *price* under *items* property.

```
beerStoreArray.forEach(function (store) {
    store['items'] = [];
    store['items'].push({itemName: "Light Beer", price: 10});
    store['items'].push({itemName: "Heavy Beer", Price: 12})
});
```